# Can I remove DECLARE @BRPS BIGINT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to use this query in Java code:

```
DECLARE @BRPS BIGINT
SELECT @BRPS=cntr_value 
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name LIKE 'Batch Requests/sec%'
WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:10'
SELECT (cntr_value-@BRPS)/10.0 AS "Batch Requests/sec"
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name LIKE 'Batch Requests/sec%'
```

When I remove `DECLARE @BRPS BIGINT` I get error. Can you help me to rewrite this code into simple SQL query wit the same result?

Answer (score 2):

There are many flaws in there...

First of all: No, you cannot remove the `DECLARE` if you want to store a value into a variable which you want to use later.

Second: If you write a value into a variable the result must be scalar. That means: one column from one row. Using `LIKE 'Batch Requests/sec%'` looks like you expect several possible results... Try it like

```
DECLARE @BRPS BIGINT=(SELECT cntr_value 
                      FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
                      WHERE counter_name = 'Batch Requests/sec');

SELECT @BRPS;
```

Third: What do you expect? Try:

```
SELECT cntr_value FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE counter_name = 'Batch Requests/sec';
WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:10';
SELECT cntr_value FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE counter_name = 'Batch Requests/sec';
GO
SELECT cntr_value FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE counter_name = 'Batch Requests/sec';
GO
SELECT cntr_value FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE counter_name = 'Batch Requests/sec';
```

Fourth: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, this is a **very** broad question, and has nothing to do with the initial question you gave here ("Can I remove ..."). I'd suggest the following: Please vote up and accept this answer as it really answers your initial question. Then think about your goals and place a new question with clear description **what** you want to monitor. This might be better in [StackExchange:DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). If you place a link here, I'll try to help you. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi @PeterPenzov, I saw that you were just around... Is this question still open?

Comment: @ yes, please post your proposal.

Comment: @PeterPenzov, No, this question is "Can I remove `DECLARE @BRPS BIGINT`?" and you've got a full and clearly argumented answer on this. As pointed out, your new question is - uhm - a new question and much to broad to be answered!

Comment: @PeterPenzov, I don't know what you really expect, but [please read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266767/5089204)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ctn VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @ctn = CAST(cntr_value AS BINARY(8)) 
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name LIKE 'Batch Requests/sec%'
SET CONTEXT_INFO @ctn

GO ----

SELECT [Batch Requests/sec] = (cntr_value - CAST(SUBSTRING(CONTEXT_INFO(), 1, 8) AS BIGINT)) / 10.
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name LIKE 'Batch Requests/sec%'
```